# Mysql select value depending in condition

Tags: mysql, pivot

```
Date | ID  |  Value
10-01  01  100
10-01  02  200
10-01  03  300
10-02  01  1000
10-02  02  2000
10-02  03  3000
```

My table has a daily entry for every id, with a different value per entry.

I need the query to show:

```
ID  Date1Value  Date2Value
01   100       1000
02   200       2000
03   300       3000
```

Date 1 will be `DATE_SUB(curdate(), Interval 1 DAY)`, while Date2 is `DATE_SUB(curdate(), Interval 2 DAY)`

Comment: How many dates do you have, and would you expect the need to add an arbitrary number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional aggregation` for this:

```
select id, 
       max(case when date = date_sub(curdate(), Interval 1 DAY) 
                then value
           end) date1value,
       max(case when date = date_sub(curdate(), Interval 2 DAY) 
                then value
           end) date2value
from yourtable
group by id
```